# Trouble getting leaflet-label plugin to work on geojson file

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, mapbox

I cannot figure out how to get labels on my featureLayers to show in my LeafLet map for a mapbox featureLayer using the leaflet-label plugin. I thought all i needed to do was add

```
.bindLabel('Look revealing label!')
```

Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>A Site Survery of Antikythera Greece</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.3.0/mapbox.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.3.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <!--labeling scripts-->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-label/v0.2.1/leaflet.label.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-label/v0.2.1/leaflet.label.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>



//load the map

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwcGluZ3RoaW5ncyIsImEiOiJkSy1MRlNVIn0.jt2ol5HlgFaCdx4Ajn5WjA';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([35.87, 23.3], 14);

// Load all the layers in

L.marker([35.87, 23.3]).bindLabel('Look revealing label!').addTo(map);

var geologyLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(geologyLayer, {
    style: {
    "color": "Black",
    "weight": 3,
    "opacity": .5,
    }
})
    .loadURL('http://jwitcoski.github.io/Antikythera/data/geology.geojson')
    .bindLabel('Look revealing label!')
    .addTo(map);


//map legend

L.control.layers({
    'Mapbox Satellite': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.satellite').addTo(map),
    'Mapbox Light': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.light'),
    'Thunderforest Outdoors' : L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.thunderforest.com/">Thunderforest</a>, &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }),
    'MtbMap' : L.tileLayer('http://tile.mtbmap.cz/mtbmap_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &amp; USGS'
        }),
    'Esri_WorldImagery' : L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
        attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
        }),

    },
    {

    "Geology": geologyLayer,
}).addTo(map);
;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like bindLabel doesn't work as expected with asynchronously loaded data with loadURL(). If you pass geojson directly, it works:

```js
// jQuery usage just for the sake of brevity
jQuery.get('http://jwitcoski.github.io/Antikythera/data/geology.geojson').success(function(data) {
  var geologyLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(data, {
    style: {
      "color": "Black",
      "weight": 3,
      "opacity": .5,
    }
  })
  .bindLabel('look label')
  .addTo(map);
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome thanks.  Just needed to add jquery library <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>